# SASS Compass and MS FIlters: Using Image-url with an MS Filter

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

In compass you can use [image-url](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url) to specify the path to your image directory.

I want to use the following Microsoft Filter in my code.

```
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='arrow-big-right.png', sizingMethod='scale');
```

In this code, you have to specify the path to the image. I want to use image-url to do this. That way, if I change my image directory, the paths will always be the same. Is this possible in SASS/Compass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, so long as you wrap `image-url()` with `#{}`:

```sass
body
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=#{image-url('arrow-big-right.png')}, sizingMethod='scale')
```